# Is there a relation between variance and range where we take iid random samples, does range goes to $0$ in probability means the same for for variance

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, concentration-of-measure

First, we consider, as in elementary statistics, **a fixed size (say $n$, but can assume $n=2$ to start with, to eventually relax this)** sample $\{x^{m}_1\dots x^{m}_n\}\subset \mathbb{R}.$ Belo, unless otherwise implied $m\to \infty.$ Then it's easy to see that their common variance $V^{(m)}$ satisfies $V^{(m)}\le {R^{(m)}}^2,R^{(m)} = max \{x^{m}_1\dots x^{m}_n\} - min \{x^{(m)}_1\dots x^{(m)}_n\}.$ So it's clear that as $R^{(m)}\to 0, V^{(m)}\to 0$ as well. Indeed it's also true that as $V^{(m)}\to 0, R^{(m)}\to 0,$ without having to use any inequality between $V^{(m)}$ and $R^{(m)}.$

Next, we work with an iid random sample as in probability theory, where by random sample, we mean an iid set of random variables $\{X^{(m)}_1\dots X^{(m)}_n\}: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}, X_i^{(m)} \sim X^{(m)}$ (has the same distribution as $X.$). Now here the variance $V^{(m)}$ of $X^{(m)}$ is a sequence of nonnegatve real numbers whereas the range $R^{(m)}$ is a random variable.

I was wondering whether there's a (probabilistic) inequality that connects $R^{(m)}$ with $V^{(m)}?$ And finally, can we say that $R^{(m)}\to 0$ in distribution/in probability/almost surely/in some $L^p$ norm implies $V^{(m)}:= Var[X^{(m)}]\to 0?$

How about the converse? Does $V^{(m)}\to 0, m\to \infty$ implies $R^{(m)}\to 0$ in distribution/in probability/almost surely/in some $L^p$ norm?

P.S. As hinted through the comments, we can specify that $n$ is fixed, and the  thus we can take $n=2.$ But eventually it'd be nice to see the dependence on $n$ as well.

P.P.S. I asked the question on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/435785/is-there-a-relation-between-variance-and-range-where-we-take-iid-random-samples) just now.

Comment: To clarify, when taking the limit $X$ changes (obviously) but $n$ stays the same, right? The question already makes sense for fixed $n = 2$ and changing $X$. It is may be wise to first consider some cases where we understand exactly *how* $X$ changes, i.e. specify a series of $X$'s (perhaps with upper indices, or indices within parentheses or something) and verify that the result is true there.

Comment: @Vincent Thank you for your valued comment - I edited the question.

Comment: In the second part of your question, is $V^{(m)}$ the empirical variance of $X_1^{(m)},...X_n^{(m)}$ as in the first part ? Is so, $V^{(m)}$ is a random variable that satisfy the same inequality as in your first part. 

If this is not how you defined $V^{(m)}$, please be more precise : the variance (as defined in probability for a signle real-valued random variable) is not defined for an $n$-uple of random variables.

Comment: @MathMax Thank you for your comment, I edited the question!